# InfluxDB select top n results from a group by tag

Tags: influxdb

I have a data set of devices and the number of (un)instalmments of my app that are done daily.

A sample data would be:

```
 time | device_name | daily_installs | daily_uninstall
  t1  |   device1   |       0        |       1
  t1  |   device2   |       2        |       0
  t2  |   device2   |       2        |       0
  t2  |   device3   |       12       |       0
```

I can group them by device_name and get the total of install that I have by month (or any other range) for example.

But the amount of device is huge, hence I would like to filter only the top 10.

How can I achieve that using InfluxDB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer depends on which version of InfluxDB you're using.

### Version 1.1-

#### Step 1

Select the monthly counts into a new measurement

```
SELECT count(daily_uninstall) as monthly_uninstall
INTO newmeasurement 
FROM mymeasurement
WHERE time > now() - 4w
GROUP BY device_name
```

#### Step 2

Select the top 10 results from the new measurement

```
SELECT top(monthly_uninstall, 10), device_name
FROM newmeasurement
```

## Version 1.2+

In versions 1.2+ of InfluxDB you'll be able to do this in a single step using subqueries.

```
SELECT top(monthly_uninstalls,10), device_name
FROM (SELECT count(daily_uninstall) as monthly_uninstall 
      FROM mymeasurement 
      WHERE time > now() - 4w
      GROUP BY device_name)
```

Comment: Hi @Michael, I am using inflaxDB version 1.22 and I run your last example (without Step 1 / 2 ) but it returns null in device name. What am I missing ?

Comment: Try using the latest version. Subqueries have had a number of associated bugs in v1.2.2

Comment: Thanks I did, the syntax have changed a little bit so I added it.

Comment: when i use the query like this, the all point's device_name are the same!!!

Answer (score 11):

**Version 1.3.4**

```
SELECT top(monthly_uninstalls,device_name,10) 
FROM (SELECT count(daily_uninstall) as monthly_uninstall 
      FROM mymeasurement 
      WHERE time > now() - 4w 
      GROUP BY device_name)
```

Please note that the syntax is "top("field_name", "tag", "topN") from ...."

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to change the order of the output columns?

Comment: never needed that

Comment: Is there no equivalent to the simple SQL-command 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM db' to perform this task?